# How to Load JSON Data in Django Model

Tags: json, django, django-models

I want to load below json data in my Model.

```
{
    "99popularity": 79.0,
    "director": "William Cottrell",
    "genre": [
      "Animation",
      " Family",
      " Fantasy",
      " Musical",
      " Romance"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 7.9,
    "name": "Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs"
  },
  {
    "99popularity": 84.0,
    "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
    "genre": [
      "Adventure",
      " Mystery",
      " Sci-Fi"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 8.4,
    "name": "2001 : A Space Odyssey"
  },
```

I have create two models using reference to json data

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Movie(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    imdb_score = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

But in `Genre` Model i don't have any `data` and in `json` in genre section their is no `id` instead `name`. How can i load that data in my model. Please Help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: right now i am trying to read json file and trying to convert `99popularity` because it is not valid field name in django model

Comment: When you say you want to load the json into the db what do you mean? Is that inside a migration file to load this once? Or in a view where you process the json? Or are you talking about `manage.py loaddata`?

Comment: @dirkgroten in a view where you process the json

Comment: Then show us the code you have till now, so we can see what’s not working.

Comment: @dirkgroten i have made the code to rename `99popularity` to `popularity`. Now i want to ask you about `genre` because my json having `name` instead `id`. Should i also rename those `genre`. Eg: - `Animation --->>>  2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method, but you have to make the name field unique. To create two models using reference to json data, I would use a custom class method like this:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)  # make unique

class Movie(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    imdb_score = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        movie = cls.objects.create(
            popularity=kwargs['99popularity'],
            director=kwargs['director'],
            imdb_score=kwargs['imdb_score'],
            name=kwargs['name']
        )
        for genre_name in kwargs['genre']:
            genre, created = Genre.objects.get_or_create(name=genre_name)
            movie.genre.add(genre)
        return movie
```

Assuming you converted your json data to a string you can do this:

```
import json
from .models import Movie

# you can also keep this inside a view
with open('movie_data.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    json_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

    for movie_data in json_data:
        movie = Movie.create(**movie_data)
        # movie and genres created
```

Comment: Your code gave me good idea how to do it. I am confused how to load that json data. because i am not using fixture

Comment: If you have a json file you can use this question on how to convert it to a dict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file

Comment: Thanks you understood my actual question. This was my first time to play with json file in Python

Comment: @gormih yes, you can use `bulk_create` for big datasets.